# Create responsive Square div inside rectangle div

Tags: css, reactjs

I have a div to be a navigation header with the following css.
This covers the total screen width

```
.upper-div {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}
```

Inside the upper div is a smaller div with the following css

```
height: 40px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 40px;
  margin: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 12px;
  cursor: pointer;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  background-color: #e3e6ef;
  margin-left: 2%;
```

How can I make the smaller div responsive to become smaller when going lower screen size?

Comment: Use responsive units of measure instead of hardcoding in pixels for `width`, `margin`, `border-radius` and `padding`

Comment: So in this case percentages will be a bit of a problem because the smaller div wont be a square anymore

Answer (score 0):

Logically, you can set to your smaller div :

```
width: 95% (or wahtever you want)
```

And on your .upper-div :

```
display: flex;    
justify-content: center;
```

The smaller div will always be smaller, and always in the center (left and right).

Is it what you want ? If I don't correctly understand whart you want, tell me and I adapt my answer